# how to hide the text limit line in netbeans 6.5?

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to hide the text limit line in netbeans 6.5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

line is not moving to 200 column, but you can hide it setting its color to same as the background

Comment: For those wondering _how_ to change the colour, it's in `Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Highlighting -> Text Limit Line -> Foreground`

Comment: If you're a perfectionist, set it to an alpha of 0. Because anytime you select the line of code, you will see the vertical limit line of whatever color the background is.

Answer (score 32):

In NetBeans 6.9, setting Right Margin to 0 effectively hides the text limit line.
Set the value in Preferences > Editor > Formatting > All Languages > Right Margin.
*(Mac OS X 10.6.4, NetBeans 6.9)*

Answer (score 6):

You can set it to 0. So It will not be visible.

Answer (score 5):

Are you talking about the line running thru the right side, by default at the 80 column point?  That is Options -> Editor -> Indentation -> Right margin.  I have it set at 200 columns which pushes it off the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Hi~ I found out how to hide "Text limit line" :)

1. Tools -> Options -> Export(Popup Win) -> Browse.. (Select target "*ccc.zip*" file)
   Select Options for Export : Check at "Editor" -> OK
2. Edit xml file "**\Editors\Preferences\org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml**" in "*ccc.zip*" file.

   ```
   <entry javaType="java.lang.Boolean" name="text-limit-line-visible" xml:space="preserve">
   <value><![CDATA[false]]></value></entry>
   ```
3. Tools -> Options -> Import "*ccc.zip*" file

Done

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I've been looking for this for a while and this works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

As for now (October '18) in NetBeans **8.2** + **9** you can hide the *text limit line* or actually change its color by going to Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Highlighting -> Text Limit Line -> Foreground

Answer (score 0):

Remember to go to tools, options, fonts & colors, highlighting tab, text limit line selected before exporting ccp.zip....

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to disable the warning generated by NetBeans for number of lines.

Goto **Tools > Options > Editor > Hints**

Find the checkbox **Too Many Lines** > un-check the checkbox

and click **Apply**.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see if your project properties have formatting that overwrites the global properties?

See below:
https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=223329