# Insert Break After Wrapping Width 80 characters in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

In sublime text 3, it will be nice if a line break is inserted after wrapping the code after 80 characters. However, I have not found this plugin yet. Does anyone know the configuration/plugin?

I found the link for wrapping lines after 80 characters. [80-characters / right margin line in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900954/80-characters-right-margin-line-in-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [AutoWrap](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoWrap). It will hard wrap automatically whenever you hit the ruler. It works nearly perfectly for me.

Comment: Been looking for something like this forever. Most suggestions always just point to word wrapping which is only a local fix but won't retain the line width when pushing to source control. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't break (add next-line character) when I go beyond set line width of say 80 columns

Answer (score 11):

I successfully used [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) find-replace in Sublime Text:

replace

```
(.{80})
```

with

```
$1\n
```

Comment: If you don't want to break words, replace `(.{0,80})\s` rather than `(.{80})`

Comment: @Lithy Your solution is THE solution! Thanks for sharing it.